# Duplicate Google account when using the same account on different devices

Tags: windows-10, chromebook, google-accounts

I am on Chromebook and Windows 10. One day, I was on the same document on both computers and there was a duplicate account under the same email. I want to know why this happens.

Comment: what do you mean a 'duplicate account '

Comment: A Google doc I have was open on both computers, and Google treated it as if I had two seperate accounts for each device, under the same email. Thus, there were two accounts appearing in the area where it would show the people on the doc.

Comment: I would love to help but I still do not understand.  I tried to figure out what you are explaining by editing a google doc with the same account but from two locations but can't.  You need to use the language of the app (I click on menu 'x' or button 'y').  For example, if I open a google doc and click on 'document details' I see 'x' when I expect to see 'y'.  If difficult to explain, maybe some screenshots.  A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: any luck Andrew?

Comment: After the clarification comment, I think I understand the question. That's actually how Google's collaborative services work: showing the same account on different devices as a separate entity since they can still edit the document at the same time on different sections. On the other hand, now I realize that this question might not be really related to computing hardware and should have been migrated to [webapps.se] since this is specifically about how Google Docs/Sheets/Slides work...